# How to extract the hyperlink cell from excel sheet using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, xlrd, xlwt

I am trying to open the hyperlinks of the individual cells in excel spreadsheet.This is the code i tried

```
import xlrd
import logging
wb=xlrd.open_workbook("hhh.xls")
sh=wb.sheet_by_index(3)
wsname=[]
for row in range(sh.nrows):
    if sh.cell_value(row,15)=="Table":
        print sh.cell_value(row,15)
        print sh.cell_value(row,2)

        link =sh.hyperlink_map.get(row,2)
        url='(No URL)' if link is None else link.url_or_path
        wsname = link.textmark.split('!')[0]
        logging.debug("link=%s wsname=%s" % (link.textmark, wsname))
        wstable=wb.sheet_by_name(wsname)
```

Please help me the problem
this is the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reading.py", line 12, in 
    url='(No URL)' if link is None else link.url_or_path
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'url_or_path'

help........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Sheet.hyperlink_map-attribute), you need to pass in a *tuple*:

```
link = sh.hyperlink_map.get((row,2))
```

Comment: hi burhan, i tried that pls check the code whether is working or not.

Comment: i want to open the particular cell hyperlink from excel sheet .Is there any other way

Comment: You didn't try it - look at your code, and then look at my snippet.

Comment: can you give me your mail id. pls because am working in python excel ., so can you please help me if i get doubt at some time.